# c++ namespace problem

Tags: c++, g++, static-libraries

hi 
can any one help me with this code. i'm new to c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace manish
{
  double mean(double a, double b);
}

double mean(double a, double b)
{
  return (a+b) / 2;
}
```

i want to make a static libray for this i use the command
 g++ calc_mean.cpp -o mean.o
 it give me following error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
```

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?
or how to make a namespace for a function so that it can be used in another place by using its name space

Comment: Why have you declared mean in the manish namespace, but defined it anonymously. Also, this question has nothing to do with namespaces, but how to compile a static library using GCC.

Comment: have a look here to make a static library to calculate the mean: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using -o which means the compiler expects the files to create a complete program. However, a complete program must contain a main() function. You should use:

```
g++ -c calc_mean.cpp
```

If you do not have a main function.

Answer (score 9):

This is nothing to do with namespaces. If you want to compile and not link you have to provide the `-c` option to gcc:

```
g++ -c calc_mean.cpp -o mean.o
```

The error you are getting is because g++ is trying to create an executable program (you haven't told it otherwise) for which you need to define the standard entry point: `main`.

There is nothing inherently wrong with declaring a `mean` in one namespace and defining another `mean` at global namespace scope, although in this instance the first declaration is not used so doesn't have any effect.

To make a static library from the resulting object file you need to use the archive utility (`ar`). E.g.:

```
ar rcs libmean.a mean.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Build with `g++ -c` option to tell gcc to not invoke the linker, since you are building library and have nothing to link.

Answer (score 0):

main is the function that will called when your program loads. You're telling compiler to create a program that when run will have a main function.

add this to your code

```
void main(){
  printf("My program has started");
}
```

Also you have declared a function called manish::mean (mean function in the manish namespace) but you have provided the code for the function mean in the global namespace ::mean

you  should try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace manish
{
  double mean(double a, double b);

  double mean(double a, double b)
  {
    return (a+b) / 2;
  }
}

void main(){
  double result = manish::mean(2.0, 4.0);
  printf("My program has started - the result is %f", result);
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is incorrect. `main` _must_ have a return type of `int`.